# How to use jquery .load and keep javascript functionality in original document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am having an issue involving jquery slider. I am calling 3 different php codes to go within a div depending on slider position. Problem is the other javascripts on the page/document, which includes jplayer, hover and other functionality, only work on the first instance (the "0" default setting of the slider). I think the problem is that when the other settings' code are inserted through slider change, they don't remain in the original document which has the original javascript - instead a new document (and file path) is executed - but I can't figure out how to just insert the php code and keep the original document and javascript functionality.

Here is the slider script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value:0,
        min: 0,
        max: 2,
        step: 1,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            var pyrScrURL = "pyrScr" + ui.value + ".1.8.php";
            $("#pyr").load(pyrScrURL);
        }
    }); 
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
</script>
```

Here is the div html, with the default "0" php file included:

```
<div id="pyr">
    <?php include("pyrScr0.1.8.php");?>
</div><!--end pyr div-->
```

Here is an example of script which does not work after the slider is moved, even though the html runs fine:

```
// hover
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".counter, .counterPM").hover(function(){
    var currentId = $(this).data("id");
    var currentRank = $(this).data("rank");
    var currentTitle = $(this).data("song_name");
    /*alert("the current title is " + currentTitle);*/
    $("#songName").html(currentTitle);
});
});
```

Thank you in advance for your advice and assistance.

Comment: is the jplayer inside the `#pyr`? also is `counterPM` inside `#pyr`

Comment: jplayer is in the head and not in `#pyr`. `counterPM` is not in `#pyr` but in a related div. `counter` is in `#pyr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying a lot of things, here is what worked for me. I had to add the javascript link tags for the scripts I wanted to run **into** the php files which were being included as part of the slider change event.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/hover.js"></script>

<?php 
...
?>
```

I had thought that I could just use the script tags in the main document head to reference all included files - but I guess not.

So now those js script tags are both in the main document, as well as in the included php files.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are inserting dom elemnts through the `change` function. The [jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method may do the trick.

Hope this helps, good luck.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.counter, .counterPM', function(){
    var currentId = $(this).data('id'),
        currentRank = $(this).data('rank'),
        currentTitle = $(this).data('title');

    $('#songName').html(currentTitle);
}
```

Comment: Hi, replacing with your suggested code does not seem to work. Is there anything I should change in the rest of the code to make this work?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? That method was added to jQuery 1.7.

Comment: jquery-1.9.1 - I think there is some other issue